# Starcraft 2 Global Achievements Statistics

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

Is there a way to see Global Achievements info? i.e. "% of all
players" for each achievement?
Similiar to the way you can see in Steam.
It's kinda interesting for achievement collectors to see how rare their achievements are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a starting point for you, you can find your profile and then in your profile it will show you statistics of the achievements world wide.

http://www.sc2ranks.com/ach/all/